Application Insight - different failed requests count between tabs
I am quite new to Azure solutions. I think there is something wrong with my Failures tab configuration or maybe I don't understand how it works. In this tab I can find all the failed requests in my application.
On my prod env I can see that the number of failed requests count is greater than the list of operation/dependency names. It does not happen on QA env, only on preprod, is this correct behaviour?
Please have a look at the screenshot below.

In the top bottom graph, we can see that there is a 16 “failed dependency” and its agree with the right tab "Overall", where is 16 response codes. But if we look at the bottom tab “Dependency name” we can see that there are only 3 request operations. Why there is such a significant difference?
Same case we can observe on tab “Operations”.
This situation does not occur on QA env, as I mentioned in the first paragraph.
Additional screen:


Once check the configuration settings for QA and Production.

You can see the correct count in the Logs section.

Yes I can see correct count in Logs section. Query result return same number as it is in "Dependency section", but it leads to misunderstandings.

@Harshitha any other idea?

If you look at the graph on the screen it looks like there are 16 failed requests. (1 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 4 + 1)
This matches the 16 (11 + 3 + 1 + 1) failed requests on the right of the screen.
There is a period selected on the graph 8:29 - 9:09, this appears to have the 3 failed requests listed below the graph.

I don't buy it, please take a look at additional screen which I uploaded few minutes ago in main question.
Period is between 10:33 and 10:45 and failures requests has occurred in this period (marked with purple line)
